# Permutation group of Cosets

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, permutations

Let $K$ be a subgroup of a group $G$. Let $T$ denote the set of all distinct right cosets of $K$ in $G$ and $A(T)$ be the permutation group of $T$. Prove the following statements.

(a) For each $a\in G$, the function $f_a:T\rightarrow T$ given by $f_a(Kb)=K(ba)$ is a bijection.

(b) The function $\varphi:G\rightarrow A(T)$ given by $\varphi(a)=f_{a^{-1}}$ is a group homomorphism whose kernel is contained in $K$.

I have been able to work out part (a) and most of part (b). I am stuck on the last part of (b) where I am asked to verify that $Ker(\varphi)\subset K$. To do this we need to know the identity element of $A(T)$ which is clearly the identity permutation. In this context that should be the $f_e$ mapping. But this gives me that $Ker(\varphi)=\{e\}$ which doesn't seem correct. Also there is a part (c) that says to prove that if $K$ is normal then $Ker(\varphi)=K$ so I'm pretty sure that I'm wrong but I can't seem to make anymore progress. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the adjustment!  You can always ask "part 2" after understanding answers to (a, b), if you need to!

Comment: Suppose that $g\in G$ has $f_{g^{-1}}$ the identity map. that means that for every $b\in G$, $Kbg^{-1} = Kb$, which requires $bgb^{-1}\in K$ for all $b\in G$. That does **not** mean, necessarily, that $g=e$. However, you should be able to deduce that it does *imply* that $g\in K$.

Comment: I did write that down at one point, however all I could come up with was that $g=b^{-1}kb$ for some $k\in K$. Why is $b^{-1}kb\in K$ for all $b\in G$? All we really know is that $K$ is a general subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h\in Ker(\varphi)$. Note that if your $f_{h^{-1}}$ is the identity permutation, then in particular $f_{h^{-1}}(K)=Kh^{-1}=K$ and this implies that $h^{-1}\in K$ and also its inverse does since $K$ is a subgroup.

Conversely, suppose $K$ is normal and $h \in K$. Then $f_{g^{-1}}(Kb)=Kbg^{-1}$, $f_{g^{-1}h^{-1}}(Kb)=Kbg^{-1}h^{-1}$ and $f_{h^{-1}g^{-1}}(Kb)=Kbh^{-1}g^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$. But $Kbg^{-1}h^{-1}=bg^{-1}Kh^{-1}=bg^{-1}K=Kbg^{-1}$ and $Kbh^{-1}g^{-1}=Kbg^{-1}$ by normality of $K$, so you have that $\varphi(hg)=\varphi(gh)=\varphi(g)$, which implies that $\varphi(h)$ is the identity. So $K$ is included in the kernel and using the first inclusion we conclude that $K=Ker(\varphi)$.